# How to split string by my own delimiter

Tags: c++, string, extract, getline, istringstream

The program should take as input the digit infused string and the digit delimiter, and output the 4 words on separate lines.

Example

```
Please enter a digit infused string to explode: You7only7live7once
Please enter the digit delimiter: 7
The 1st word is: You
The 2nd word is: only
The 3rd word is: live
The 4th word is: once
```

Hint: getline() and istringstream will be helpful.

I'm having trouble finding how/where to use getline() correctly.

Below is my program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
string userInfo;
cout << "Please enter a digit infused string to explode:" << endl;
cin >> userInfo;
istringstream inSS(userInfo);
string userOne;
string userTwo;
string userThree;
string userFour;
inSS >> userOne;
inSS >> userTwo;
inSS >> userThree;
inSS >> userFour;
cout << "Please enter the digit delimiter:" << endl;
int userDel;
cin >> userDel;
cout <<"The 1st word is: " << userOne << endl;
cout << "The 2nd word is: " << userTwo << endl;
cout << "The 3rd word is: " << userThree << endl;
cout << "The 4th word is: " << userFour <<endl;

return 0;
}
```

My current output is this

```
Please enter a digit infused string to explode:
Please enter the digit delimiter:
The 1st word is: You7Only7Live7Once
The 2nd word is: 
The 3rd word is: 
The 4th word is:
```

Comment: Output `userDel` and tell me what it says. :)

Comment: well you don't use your `userDel` in any way, this is kinda expected

Comment: So are you wondering where to use a specific function you might not even need rather than actually implementing the required task? Why?

Comment: Helpful reading: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: userDel = 7 and I haven't outputted it because I have to find a way to detect it and go around it to output the words.

Comment: Also, I figured I needed getline() to complete the required task. no?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have been looking for. Note that [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) can take optional third parameter `char delim`, where you tell it to stop reading there instead of at the end of the line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string userInfo, userOne, userTwo, userThree, userFour;
    char userDel;

    cout << "Please enter a digit infused string to explode:" << endl;
    cin >> userInfo;
    istringstream inSS(userInfo);

    cout << "Please enter the digit delimiter:" << endl;
    cin >> userDel;

    getline(inSS, userOne, userDel);
    getline(inSS, userTwo, userDel);
    getline(inSS, userThree, userDel);
    getline(inSS, userFour, userDel);

    cout <<"The 1st word is: " << userOne << endl;
    cout << "The 2nd word is: " << userTwo << endl;
    cout << "The 3rd word is: " << userThree << endl;
    cout << "The 4th word is: " << userFour <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`cin >> userInfo;` will consume everything up to a space.

Whereas `getline(cin, userInfo);` will consume everything up to the new line character.

I guess in your case it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Yes, but what if you take advantage of `getline`'s third parameter?